# SVM in R, value of cost doesn't affect test error rate

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am currently using SVMs in R (e1071) with linear kernels to attempt to classify a high dimensional data set. It consists of around 300 patients with around 12000 gene activity levels measured for each patient. My goal is to predict patient response (binary: treatment effective or not) to a certain drug based upon these gene activities.

I want to establish the range of cost values to pass to the tune.svm function and this is where I am running into trouble. My understanding is that the way to do this is to try progressively smaller and larger values until lower and upper bounds for reasonable performance are respectively established; nevertheless, when I attempt to do this, no matter how large or small I make my possible costs, my resulting test error rate is never worse than about 50%. This is happening both with my actual data set and with this toy version. If this subset is too small I can provide a more significant chunk of it. Thanks for any advice.

My code:

```
dat.ex <- read.table("svm_ex.txt", header=T, row.names=1)
trainingSize <- 20
possibleCosts <- c(10^-50, 10^-25, 10^25, 10^50)
trainingDat <- sample(1:dim(dat.ex)[1], replace = FALSE, size = trainingSize)
ex.results <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(possibleCosts))
{
  svm.ex <- svm(dat.ex[trainingDat, -1], factor(dat.ex[trainingDat, 1]), kernel="linear", cost=possibleCosts[i], type="C-classification")
  test.ex <- predict(svm.ex, newdata=data.frame(x = dat.ex[-trainingDat,-1]))
  truth.ex <- table(pred = test.ex, truth = factor(dat.ex[-trainingDat,1]))
  exTestCorrectRate <- (truth.ex[1,1] + truth.ex[2,2])/(dim(dat.ex)[1] - trainingSize)
  ex.results[i] <- exTestCorrectRate  
}
print(ex.results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you try ugly weird values of `C`. You should check the much smaller range of values (say between `1e-15` and `1e10`) and in much geater resolution ( for example - 25 different values for the interval I suggested).

Second, you have very small dataset. 20 training vectors with 10 dimensions may be hard to model

Comment: I added more data (now there are 50 observations on 80 features). Shouldn't there be values of cost where the value is so extreme that the model is unable to classify almost every observation? Using the larger data set that I added, when I run cost = `1e-50` I get that 73% of observations were correctly predicted. This seems impossible to me. I thought that when costs get that microscopic then the model   grossly overfits and performs extremely poorly on the test data. How can this model perform so well?

Comment: Model overfits for **large** cost, not small. Cost is the `C` parameter in the original formulation of the SVM equation. it defines the separability "force" - with C going to infinity you get the hard-margin classifier, with C going to zero - you let more and more points to be missclassified during training. Even though linear model are not prone to overfitting as you have very strong limitation on possible model's complexity. Btw. R is using double to store numerical values, so setting so astronomic values as 1e-50 or 1e50 has great chance of leading some numerical under/overflow.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up low vs. high cost. I tried with cost in c(10^-15, ..., 10^-8) and for all but one of these the correct test prediction rate is >= 60% which still seems quite high. Similarly, for cost in c(1e9, .. 1e16) the correct test prediction rate was between 53% and 87%. 87% correct with C = 1e16 seems too good to be true. I was expecting that extremely large costs would give me correct prediction rates of around 0% due to overfitting. Is that not actually true?

Comment: As I said before - **linear** SVM won't overfit in many cases because  it is too simple model. Also remember, that testing on just one part of your data is not a good estimate of your model correctness. You should use cross-validation to find the more reasonable results

Comment: I tried this example with a radial kernel and used (cost, gamma) = {(1e10, 1e5), (1e10, 1e-5), (1e-10, 1e5), (1e-10, 1e-5)}. I repeated this 100 times with a different subset for my training data each time. What I got is that the worst performance was an error rate of 0.339 and the best performance was an error rate of 0.103. Am I still making the same mistake? I can't imagine that a cost of 1e10 and a gamma of 1e-5 should actually perform well.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. In the full data set approximately 2/3 of the responses are 1 and 1/3 are 0. For these extreme parameters, every response was predicted to be 1 and thus test error rates in the range of 50% - 80% (with some fluctuations occurring due to training data selection) kept occurring.